# redirect page on specific user detection asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i would like how to implement the following in asp.net:

i have windows authentication and i would like the server to detect who the user is and redirect the page depending on the username on the page.

is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the username like...

```
string username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
```

Once you have the username you can redirect the page to a specific page.

**Edit:** You can do it in `Application_AuthenticateRequest` event, that is `Global.asax` file

```
 protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
      // put code here....
    }
 }
```

Comment: thanks so much, can you tell me in which event i can put this?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Secondly I would recommend to read this article http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/07/12/Recipe_3A00_-Enabling-Windows-Authentication-within-an-Intranet-ASP.NET-Web-application.aspx

Comment: works beautifully!!!! how do i do this with ROLES instead of USER string username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();

Comment: I guess, you did not check the provided URL!!!, Anyway, you can do like.. if(HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(@"DomainName\Manager"))

Comment: what is the reason we put this in the application _authentication instead of page_load?

Comment: This event called whenever request is made and in life cycle it is called before page load and this is special event that used for authentication process. You can more read from internet.

Answer (score 1):

For event it depends of your code.
i supose you could do such a thing in the page_load event if you have any doubt you should check the ASP.NETlifecylce http://www.google.fr/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=asp.net+lifecycle

BTW you can use Response.redirect to redirect the user.

Answer (score 1):

pretty straightforward

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();

       if (username == "someusername")
       {
          Response.Redirect("someaspxfile.aspx");
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for picking up the control with username in it, it will be available in the request. You can pick the data from request

Comment: can you please provide some coed